# Java 8 + JavaFX on macOS: "ERROR: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application."

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

My JavaFX application works perfectly on Windows, where I have Java 1.8.0_221. The application is a fat jar with `jfxrt.jar` included in the jar, so all JavaFX libraries should be inside there.

However, when I try to run the same jar on macOS (still Java 8), it's not able to launch, and I'm greeted with the following error message: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.`

What can I do to fix this? Why is it behaving differently between the operating systems? Thank you so much for your help!

**Note:** I realize that other users have asked about this error message in the past, but the error I have is on Java 8 and is not connected to Java 11/OpenJFX 11 - hence, I believe that the causes are different and this shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: You should not include the jfxrt.jar in your fat jar. For Java 8 this is part of the JRE and contains platform specific code.

Comment: @mipa Oh okay. If I don't do that though, then the application just fails to launch on macOS, reporting that there was a ClassNotFoundException for "javafx/Application", meaning that it wasn't able to locate that JavaFX libraries at all. How should I proceed?

Comment: Exactly which Java 8 distribution do you have installed on your Mac? A standard OpenJDK 8, e.g, does not contain JavaFX because JavaFX was only part of the Oracle distribution. Why do you want to stay on this outdated Java version anyway? With Java 11+ things would be much easier.

Comment: I haven't tested it but this distribution might work: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-8-lts&os=&os=macos&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx

Comment: @mipa I have the standard Oracle JDK 8. I'm using Java 8, as opposed to 11, because I'm making a standard consumer application that should run on as many Windows and Mac systems as possible—presently, most users have Java 8 installed. Like you said, JavaFX should be bundled with Java 8 so there's no reason it shouldn't work... I'd rather just stick to Oracle's Java and try to get it to run on that, since most users will have Oracle's version installed.

Comment: I don't know how you back your assumption but I'd say most user nowadays do not have Java installed at all anymore. The modern trend is to bundle Java with the application so that you can distribute it like any other application and then it does not make any sense anymore to stick with an outdated version of Java. See here https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX how that can be done.

Comment: @mipa Thanks for your reply! I've redone it using javapackager, and it's fully working now. If you post your reply as an answer, I'd love to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I am glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you back your assumption but I'd say most user nowadays do not have Java installed at all anymore. The modern trend is to bundle Java with the application so that you can distribute it like any other application and then it does not make any sense anymore to stick with an outdated version of Java. See here https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX how that can be done.